# Vertical Tab displays all blocks

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

I have a Problem with a code i took from w3schools

```js
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;


    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }


    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }


    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
div.tab {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 30%;
    height: 300px;
}

div.tab button {
    display: block;
    background-color: inherit;
    color: black;
    padding: 22px 16px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

div.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

div.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 70%;
    border-left: none;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

A you can see here (https://www.alpaka-industries.de/index.php?hilfe/) it started display all blocks instead of the 2 others as none.

I cant find the issue and hope someone can help.

I know it must be the java code but actually all seems right it is set to display none but somehow it wont work.

Comment: don't post  link question  ...... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i am sorry i will add the code

Comment: Have you included bootstrap css and js in your page? I cannot find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that your code is not being called when the page loads. Try adding this to your javascript code -

```
 window.onload = function(){
    hideAllCities();
 }

function hideAllCities(){
  var tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (var i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: this worked for me fine, is there a way to show a particular tab and not to hide all tabs?

Comment: you could add the lines -
document.getElementById('CITY NAME HERE').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('CITY NAME HERE')className += " active"; after the hideAllCities() line